# Two convergent power series are the same if they equal on an infinite set of points having 0 as a limit point.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

I'm having difficulty following the proof of the theorem below.

[image]

First of all, how do we know that h(z) is a power series having a non-zero radius of convergence from the fact that f(z) is. And, how does this lead to $1+h(z) \neq 0$ for sufficiently small $|z|$?

Finally, I don't understand the proof of (b). Why does (a) imply that $h(T)$ is the zero power series? I can only conclude from (a) that $h(0)\neq 0$, since (b) implies that $h(T)$ does not satisfy the conclusion of (a).

I would greatly appreciate some explanation on these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed $z \ne 0$, the series for $f(z)$ and $1 + h(z)$ are constant multiples of one another (the constant of proportionality being $a_m z^m$). So one series converges if and only if the other does.

Since $1 + h(z)$ converges in some disk around $0$, it is continuous there. (I presume this fact is known to you. It is a consequence of the uniform convergence of the partial sums within the open disk of convergence.) Therefore, the value of $1 + h(z)$ is within $\epsilon = 1$ of $1$ for values of $z$ close enough to $0$.

For part (b), if $h(T)$ weren't the zero power series, then by part (a) it would take only nonzero values in some neighbourhood of $0$ (except at $0$ itself). This contradicts the hypothesis that $0$ is an accumulation point of values $z$ for which $h(z) = 0$.

Comment: why is it that if $h(T)$ weren't the zero power series, then by part (a) it would take only nonzero values in some neighbourhood of 0? How do we know that h(0)=0, in order to apply (a)?

Comment: that's the part (a) : if $h(T)$ is not the zero power series and $h(0) = 0$ then there exists $U$ a neighborhood of $0$ such that $h(z) \ne 0$ on $U^*$

Comment: and $h(0) = 0$ by continuity ($h(z)$ is the difference between $A(z)$ and $B(z)$ which is supposed to be $0$ on a sequence of points converging to $z=0$)